# get and set properties

Tags: asp.net

the following code in the master.cs file

```
    public bool MenuIssuesManagementVisible   //defining the set false visibility property
    {
        get { return lnkIssuesManagement.Visible; }
        set { lnkIssuesManagement.Visible = value; }
    }

    public bool MenuTimeFilterVisible
    {
        get { return lnkTimeFilter.Visible; }
        set { lnkTimeFilter.Visible = value; }
    }
```

is setting a property which i use in a web content form in the following way-->

```
((Default)this.Master).MenuIssuesManagementVisible = false;
        ((Default)this.Master).MenuTimeFilterVisible = false;
```

but whenever i run the web content form, i get an error at the line

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Line 27:             set { lnkTimeFilter.Visible = value; }
```

how do i rectify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NullReference is coming from the line shown - there's only one object reference there - lnkTimeFilter is null. Beyond that it's hard to say with the information you've provided. Perhaps it is not a direct child of the master page? Where is lnkTimeFilter declared?

Answer (score 0):

At what point are you calling those properties?

You won't be able to access them until after the master page is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting **MasterType** in **Page Directive** as following then you will be able to access master page public property directly as **Master.MenuIssuesManagementVisible**

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPage.master" %>
```

Look at the following links

http://www.csharpcourses.com/2008/06/access-master-page-members-from-page.html

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_ZogK56M8ygE/SFbp5tFa_rI/AAAAAAAAAJw/tky6TrQgoWU/s1600-h/Snap2-725237.jpg

Comment: @Shreya, If you feel that its a correct answer, Can you mark it as Accepted Answer thanks.